# MVC bind parameters to object

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can a model be bound to URL parameters without a prefix?

For example, with the model:

```
class Test {
    public string Value1 { get; set; }
    public string Value2 { get; set; }
}
```

With the request:

```
/test/test?value1=test&value2=test2
```

What code needs to go into the controller such that Test can be populated from the URL?

```
class TestController : Controller {
    public ActionResult Test() {
        Test test = /* ?? bind parameters from URL */;
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just add a parameter to your `Test` method `public ActionResult Test(Test model) {...`

Comment: Doesn't this require that the parameters are prefixed with "model" ?

Comment: No. The `DefaultModelBinder` creates an instance of `Test` then looks for query string parameters where the name matches a property name

Comment: For more clarity on the model binding, the query string parameters are case-INsensitive (not case-sensitive) compared to the model's property names, and the binding only works if the model's members are actual public properties with a getter/setter, not public fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

```
public ActionResult Test(string Value1, string Value2) {
    Test test = new Test();

    test.Value1 = Value1;
    test.Value2 = Value2;

    return View(test);
}

public ActionResult Test(Test test)) {
    return View(test);
}
```

In the first example, the MVC model binder will look in the request form, and url for example, for values with the name `Value1` and `Value2`. If it finds them, then it will copy those values to the named parameters `Value1` and `Value2` of the action method.

In the second example, the MVC model binder will do the same thing of looking for values, but it will use the property names of the `Test` object. In your case you have properties named `Value1` and `Value2`, thus the model binder will create a new instance of `Test` and populate it's public properties `Value1` and `Value2` for you.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to @Jason answer :

```
class TestController : Controller {
    public ActionResult Test(TestModel testModel) {
        // Normally you'll populate Test from testModel with some mapping mechanism
        // I am using Automapper as an example
        Test test = Mapper.Map<TestModel, Test>(testModel);
        ...
        return View();
    }
}
```